# Naive Suffix Array time complexity

Tags: string, algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm trying to invent programming exercise on [Suffix Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). I learned `O(n*log(n)^2)` algorithm for constructing it and then started playing with random input strings of varying length in order to find out when `naive` approach becomes too slow. E.g. I wanted to choose string length so that people will need to implement "advanced" algorithm.

Suddenly I found that `naive` algorithm (with using logarithmic sort on all suffixes) is not as slow as `O(n^2 * log(n))` means. After thinking a bit, I understand that comparison of suffixes of a randomly generated string is not `O(n)` amortized. Really, we usually only compare few first characters before we come to difference and there we return from comparison function. This of course depends on the size of the alphabet, but anyway it does not depend much on the length of suffixes.
I tried simple implementation in PHP processing `50000`-characters string in `2` seconds (despite slowness of scripting language). If it will work at least as `O(n^2)` we'll expect it to work at least several minutes (with 1e7 operations per second and ~1e9 operations total).

So I understand that even if it is `O(n^2 * log(n))` then the constant factor is a very small fraction of 1, really something close to 0. Or we should say about such complexity as `worst-case` only, right?

But what is the amortized time complexity of the naive approach? I'm bit bewildered about how to assess it.

Comment: What if your string is entirely made of the same character?

Comment: Yes, you see I've said that `O(n)` for suffix comparison is a `worst-case`... But usually we do not index such strings (except when in programming competitions, haha).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing amortized and expected complexity. In this case you are talking about expected complexity. And yes the stated complexity is computed assuming that the suffix comparison takes `O(n)`. This will be the worst case for suffix comparison and for random generated input you will only perform constant number of comparisons in most cases. Thus `O(n^2*log(n))` is worst case complexity.

One more note - on a modern computer you can perform a few **billion** elementary instructions in a second and it is possible that you execute in the order of 50000^2 in 2 seconds. The correct way to benchmark complexity of an algorithm is to measure the time it takes to complete e.g. for input of size `N, N*2, N*4,...(as many as you can go)` and then to interpolate the function that would describe the computational complexity